# How to update react state array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, immutability

I have a simple carousel type component. It has 5 slide and a current slide that can be represented by the following state.

```
this.state = {
  slides: [{
    title: "Slide One",
    class: "left-back"
  },
  {
    title: "Slide Two",
    class: "left-middle"
  },
  {
    title: "Slide Three",
    class: "front-side"
  },
  {
    title: "Slide Four",
    class: "right-middle"
  },
  {
    title: "Slide Five",
    class: "right-back"
  }],
  activeSlide: 2
};
```

I need to handle rotating this carousel and I want to do so by simply updating the classes of each slide. The actual animations will all be done with css.  To do rotate the slides to the left I have a rotateLeft function that looks like the following.

```
rotateLeft() {
  console.log('RotateLeft');
  const slides = this.state.slides.map( (slide, index, arr) => { 
    if (index === 0) {
      slide.class = arr[4].class;
    } else {
      slide.class = arr[index - 1].class;
    }
    return slide;
  });

this.setState({slides});
}
```

My idea here is to take each slide and update its class with the slide to its left. If it is the first slide take the last slide in the array's class.

This seems not to work and I assume it has to do with immutable state but I simply can't wrap my ahead around how to fix the issue.

Comment: FYI the current result is that every slide gets a class of right-back

Comment: Shouldn't you update 'activeSlide' number too ? this.setState({ slides, activeSlide : this.state.activeSlide - 1 });

Comment: perhaps on first step of map slide 0 get right-back, on next step slide 1 gets class of slide 0 which is right-back...

Comment: btw class is a reserved word in JavaScript, I wouldn't use it for variable name just as a matter of style

Comment: @FurkanO you are correct and the active slide will be updated.  It just has no relevance to this part of the code.  It is just a reference to see which way to rotate when an inactive slide is clicked.

Comment: @DmitryShvedov what you are saying is correct.  I didn't think about that.  I do think however I need to get a full deep copy then in order to do this correctly.  I can't update on the fly in either direction because the class I am trying to get will be wrong every time.

Comment: Maybe related to your problem, maybe not: `class` is a reserved keyword in JS - you should use `className` or something that is not a reserved keyword

Comment: So the problem is basically what @DmitryShvedov said. As each object in the array is updated it is referencing an object that has already been updated instead of one that has not been updated.  Leading the objects to all end up with the same class.

Comment: What you could do is instead of arr[inx] use this.state.slides[inx], because the original array is not mutated according to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

So after reading the comments above I have come to the following solution.

```
rotateLeft() {
console.log('RotateLeft');
//create a deep copy
let slides = this.state.slides.map(a => Object.assign({}, a));

//store the last class to be used later on the first object in the array
let lastClass = slides[this.state.slides.length - 1].slideClass;

slides = slides.map( (slide, index) => { 
  if (index === 0) {
    slide.slideClass = this.state.slides[this.state.slides.length - 1].slideClass;
  } else {
    slide.slideClass = this.state.slides[index - 1].slideClass;
  }
  return slide;
});

this.setState({slides, activeSlide: this.state.activeSlide + 1});
}
```

Basically, I create a deep copy of the slides in state so that I can use the current state as a reference.